# PyQGIS - Densify geometries given an interval

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have question, is it possible to make python command for QGIS function "Densify geometries given an interval":

- input layer: Polygon.shp
- output layer: Densify_interval.shp
- interval: 50 meters

for. example...

```
processing.runalg("qgis:"DENSIFY_GIVEN_AN_INTERVAL ???",input, output", interval)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can by using the following:

```
import processing
input = path/to/polygon.shp
output = path/to/output.shp
interval = 50

processing.runalg("qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval", input, interval, output)
```

---

### Some learning resources:

Seems like you're starting to learn some coding, great! You should probably take a look at the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/) to learn how to do some coding in QGIS.

Specifically, if you want to call various tools through the Python Console or through a script, you should definitely read through the topic: [Using processing algorithms from the console](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html).

I will just point out a couple of methods to help you know which algorithms are easily accessible from the **Processing** plugin and the parameters they require.

- Search for algorithm:

  ```
  processing.alglist("densify")
  ```

The above code searches through all available algorithms in Processing with the keyword "densify" and returns a list:

```
>>>processing.alglist("densify")
Densify geometries----------------------------------->qgis:densifygeometries
Densify geometries given an interval----------------->qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval
```

- Check parameter requirement:

  ```
  processing.alghelp("qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval")
  ```

Once you found an algorithm you want to use, add its full name to the above code to get the parameters you have to define:

```
>>>processing.alghelp("qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval")
ALGORITHM: Densify geometries given an interval
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    INTERVAL <ParameterNumber>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

Now you can see what each parameter needs to be defined as such as adding layer names or paths to shapefiles for the `Vectors`, adding values to `ParameterNumbers` etc. This is further described in the [Using processing algorithms from the console](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) topic.

Good luck!

Comment: You have right, I'm starting to learn some coding. I can use that tools from QGis menu but sometimes I need more. Of course thank You very much for your help in this case and thanks for resources links.

Comment: @Artec - Awesome buddy, glad I could help :)